# how to create an activity in Android

Tags: android

I am designing an app and I want that after the app is started, the user will be shown a subsection of activitys that tell him how it works or what it's used for.

I want to do something similar like what the photomath application does when it is first started by the user take a screenshot of how I would like it to be in accordance with photomath.

For me it is not important that they tell me how to do it, what I am interested in is that they tell me the name of that type of activity or that function thanks!

Comment: show what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is **FeatureDiscovery**

This GitHub [library](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) might help you out.

Try this [article](http://yasirameen.com/2016/10/android-creating-app-walkthrough/) for full example.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you need a startup activity that shows only when user first visit the app you could do that by  using shared preference and check it when the user first enter the app, also you can check google best practices documentations for the startup guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/onboarding also you can check pre-made library that will make it easier for you like this and provide animations and cool stuff : https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro